# Java 8: Better to extend class of static methods or better to call static methods directly?

Tags: java, inheritance, memory, java-8, static-methods

I'm updating some old Java 4 code to Java 8 (way too much to paste here) and the original programmer chose to have nearly every class of theirs extend this single HUGE class full of only static methods and constants, but I do not know their reasoning.

ex:

```
public class BaseClass{
     /* this class has a huge amount of ONLY static methods/constants */

     public static final int STUFF_DONE = 1;

     public static String getStuff(){
           String stuff = "this is my stuff.";
           return stuff;
     }
     ...
}

public class SuperClass extends BaseClass{
     /* this class has only a few methods */
     public String labelStuff(){
          return getStuff();
     }
}

public class MyClass extends SuperClass{
     /* there are many classes that extend SuperClass like this one */
     public int handleStuff(){
          String myString = labelStuff();
          return STUFF_DONE;
     }
     public static void main(){
          if(handleStuff()) System.out.println("Done.");
     }
}
```

My question is this... is it better to keep this design or is it better to remove the inheritance of the static methods/constants and simply call those methods/constants statically?

"Better" to me is defined as lower memory consumption (again, this base class is quite huge) as CPU is likely not affected by this.  What are the benefits/pitfalls of this approach?

My concern is that because BaseClass is so huge that I'm wasting a LOT of memory for usage of only one or two methods/constants in the inheriting classes that I could just be calling statically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static members aren't "inherited" per se. They live on the base class regardless of which subclass they're called from, so I doubt there's any memory impact.

The reason for creating all classes as a subclass of this common class is just for easy access to static members without the qualifying class name. A common variation is to inherit from an interface that declares a bunch of static fields. The upside is that implementing an interface doesn't interfere with inheritance the way a superclass would (you can only extend a single superclass). The downside is that until Java 8 it wasn't possible to declare static methods on an interface.

In any case, this trick is generally considered an anti-pattern and has been superseded by [static imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

Comment: There are many more reasons why it's an anti-pattern, but this answer is essentially correct:  It's a truly bad practice and it should be undone.  One major reason is that it couples every class to the static-method superclass.  And none of those classes can ever extend anything else.

Comment: The fact that the question is about Java 4 code and static imports have been introduced in Java 5 explains the motivation (though even before Java 5 subclassing for ease of import was considered an anti-pattern). Nevertheless it’s worth thinking about splitting the huge class into several smaller classes, maybe separating the utility methods by topic, as, when using static imports rather than inheritance, Java’s single inheritance is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is to customize the behavior of the parent class for the child classes.

Static methods cannot be inherited and their behavior does not change due to the state of the object.

So you cannot make something static and inheritable. There is no sense to extend a class of full static methods. Also, this does not change the size of the memory usage. Your classes are already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are beautiful insights written above by members. I would like to put it in different words if it helps understanding.

Inheritance : 
All the member variables and functions of parent classes are included in the child class based on visibility operator (public, private , protected )

Static members: 
The static members of class are stored in memory accessible to all instance variables of the class. It's like a shared spaced for all the instance variables belonging to that class

Now coming to inheritance of static variables and functions , it's always advisable to have static imports.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers are very useful, I would just like to add a simple point in favor of **NOT** using inheritance of the class that implements static methods: it becomes very tempting (and easy) for a developper to modify that class (add non static elements, remove the static keywords...)
and all of a sudden it becomes non static, it creates dependencies between instances that derive it, creating difficulties of initialization, multi-threading and so on.